# Mariadb Galera cluster does not come up after killing the mysql process

Tags: mariadb, cluster-computing, openstack, galera

I have a Mariadb Galera cluster with 2 nodes and it is up and running.

Before moving to production, I want to make sure that if a node crashes abruptly, It should come up on its own.

I tried using systemd "restart", but after killing the mysql process the mariadb service does not come up, so, is there any tool or method, that I can use to automate bringing up the nodes after crashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Galera clusters needs to have quorum (3 nodes).

> In order to avoid a split-brain condition, the minimum recommended number of nodes in a cluster is 3. Blocking state transfer is yet another reason to require a minimum of 3 nodes in order to enjoy service availability in case one of the members fails and needs to be restarted. While two of the members will be engaged in state transfer, the remaining member(s) will be able to keep on serving client requests.

You can read more [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/getting-started-with-mariadb-galera-cluster/).

Comment: Thanks man. I just added one more node to my cluster and it worked.